# Limit domains that PHP can send mail to

Tags: php, email

Is it possible to configure PHP to only send emails created using `mail()` to a specific list of whitelisted domains?  E.g. An email to johndoe@domain1.com is sent because domain1.com is on the whitelist but a mail to johndoe@domain2.com is dropped because domain2.com is not.  Even when the email itself is properly formed with correct headers.

PHP version 5.2.17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to prevent people sending spam, unfortunately people will always find a way to send mail from php. Even if you are able to limit the `mail()` function, nothing will prevent them from writing an own implementation that opens a socket.

So in short, there is no way to enforce this.